# Problema con un error acerca de syntax de MariaDB pero no le entiendo

Tags: php, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mariadb

alguien está familiarizado con MariaDB y la sintaxis de un INNER JOIN? Básicamente tengo dos tablas, una de ellas sería mi principal, la otra lleva llaves foráneas. Estoy seleccionando columnas de una tabla para que interactúe con mi principal, al menos así la llamo porque en el Front-End es la que muestro. La tabla "secundaria" entonces se relaciona con la "primaria". Luego voy a asistirlos con mi query que estoy manejando con PHP, primero es importante, creo mostrarles el error y enseñarles desde mi opinión lo que yo veo, desde mi perspectiva.

Error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'grupos_aa_sonora_sur.region AS region FROM meeting_hours INNER JOIN grup' at line 7
```

Line 7 es esto, basicamente es una tabla con un anexo de las columnas y un AS:

```
 meeting_hours.group_id AS grupoid,
```

La otra línea que se refiere a la sintáxis, la cuál marca que debería de usar una syntax correcta data desde la tabla principal, con sus columnas anexadas, y me indica que es alrededor de la zona que abarca el FROM y parte del INNER JOIN,
que viene siendo esta:

```
grupos_aa_sonora_sur.region AS region
    FROM meeting_hours
    INNER JOIN grupos_aa_sonora_sur
```

Ahora, yo ya he checado múltiples veces los nombres de las columnas y de las tablas, y en todas las instancias en las que he estado utilizando esta solicitud hacia la base de datos.

Este viene siendo el llamado de solicitud completo:

````
    $ciudad_query = "SELECT meeting_hours.schedule_real AS horario,
    days_of_week.day_string AS reuniones,
    meeting_hours.sessions_id AS periodo,
    meeting_hours.group_id AS grupoid,
    grupos_aa_sonora_sur.grupo AS grupo,
    grupos_aa_sonora_sur.direccion AS direccion
    grupos_aa_sonora_sur.region AS region
    FROM meeting_hours
    INNER JOIN grupos_aa_sonora_sur ON meeting_hours.group_id = grupos_aa_sonora_sur.id
    LEFT JOIN schedule_meetings ON meeting_hours.schedule_id = schedule_meetings.id
    LEFT JOIN days_of_week ON meeting_hours.sessions_id = days_of_week.day_id WHERE 1=1";```
````

Comment: Creo que te falta una coma antes del from, concretamente después del campo `direccion`

Comment: ok gracias, lo consultaré.

Comment: ya lo revisé, y si parece que eso era.

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta fue gracias a un comentario hecho por Jakala, pero debido a que un comentario no se le puede atribuir como respuesta, lo declaro en mi respuesta. Este fue el comentario de Jakala: "Creo que te falta una coma antes del from, concretamente después del campo `direccion`". Gracias, Jakala.

Comment: Es que según tengo entendido, si la respuesta es un detalle de ese tipo(no hay error en el algoritmo, solo un fsllo tipo falta de comas y demás) no se puede considerar como"respuesta". Pero gracias por la mención 

Comment: Si, por eso mismo lo hice a partir de tu comentario y usando esa opción que te da Stackoverflow de añadir un comentario propio pero en forma de respuesta.sentí que debía de incluir tu comentario ya que un comentario no puede ser seleccionado como "respuesta oficial".